# How to connect existing mysql databse to laravel 5.1

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, database-connection

Im new to laravel. 
So please describe on both way - using migration or ?

Comment: Did you read what a migration is? You just have to specify connection parameters and define models in PHP. Do read the manual before asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

migrations are database schema if you don't need subversions neither a good method to make changes available to the whole team just use them with models no need for migrations (this is not recommended) , the best practice is to create migrations so you can subversion the database easily